EF Core - Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery
I am trying to write a query that gives me the average time between status changes of an database entity. On each update an entry is created in an audit table, this table contains a Status and PreviousStatus field to allow me to easily query the changes. I am able to get the output I want via the following query but the issue is that this is being executed in memory and not in the database which is not the best solution.
//this is the best one so far but it does the average function in memory
private async Task<double> GetAvgBetweenStatus()
{
    return (await _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>().Where(x => x.Status == OpportunityStatus.Solutioned && x.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Qualified).Select(x => new
    {
        Date1 = x.AuditDate,
        Date2 = _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>().Where(o => o.OpportunityId == x.OpportunityId && o.Id < x.Id && o.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Identified).OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).First().AuditDate
    })
    .Select(x =>
        new
        {
            Duration = EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(x.Date2, x.Date1)
        })
    .ToListAsync() // <--- here it is doing the query  ) 
    .Average(x => x.Duration); // <--- this bit is done in memory / not good!
}

If I try and remove the ToListAsync() method and use AverageAsync() for example I get a "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery" exception.
It produces the following invalid SQL statement
    SELECT AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(second, (
    SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[AuditDate]
    FROM [Audit_Opportunity] AS [a0]
    WHERE [a0].[OpportunityId] = [a].[OpportunityId] AND [a0].[Id] < [a].[Id] AND [a0].[PreviousStatus] = 1), [a].[AuditDate]) AS float))
FROM [Audit_Opportunity] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Status] = 3 AND [a].[PreviousStatus] = 2

What I think I need is to add a SELECT AVG(....) FROM T like this:
** I am using datediff seconds just for testing. ***
SELECT AVG(t.Duration) FROM(
 SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, (
   SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[AuditDate]
    FROM [Audit_Opportunity] AS [a0]
    WHERE [a0].[OpportunityId] = [a].[OpportunityId] AND [a0].[Id] < [a].[Id] AND [a0].[PreviousStatus] = 1 order by [a0].Id DESC), [a].[AuditDate]) AS [Duration]
    FROM [Audit_Opportunity] AS [a]
    WHERE [a].[Status] = 3 AND [a].[PreviousStatus] = 2) AS T

No matter what I try it either causes the exception or it works but produces a mess of a query which is most likely very inefficient.
Here are the main columns which are key to this query.



Id
OpportunityId
Status
AuditDate
PreviousStatus




10049
5
1
2024-08-08 13:08:11.2210321
0


10050
5
2
2024-08-08 13:08:13.2470991
1


10051
5
3
2024-08-08 13:08:17.3099538
2


10052
5
0
2024-08-08 13:08:22.7923615
3


10053
5
1
2024-08-08 13:08:29.7530627
0


10054
5
2
2024-08-08 13:08:31.5445853
1


10055
5
3
2024-08-08 13:08:32.9252342
2


10056
5
4
2024-08-08 13:08:37.0011645
3


10057
5
2
2024-08-08 13:08:48.6677023
4




Please add a tag for your DBMS (the above looks like SQL Server). This will increase visibility to those most likely to help. Repost your sample data as text for a markdown table (not an image), so that we can cut & paste it. What is your AuditDate data type? The values posted have a weird format.  Also, your first SQL statement appears incomplete. Please fix.

Thank you, I hope I have now addressed all of your requirements.

The problem is that EF has translated your LINQ expression into a query that is syntactically (and even semantically) correct, but has run into a SQL Server limitation. The trick is to try to find an equivalent form that generates a different but supported SQL query.
If I were to code this up in SQL Server, I would use a CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...) to look up the prior (starting) audit record.  Something like:
SELECT AVG(CAST(DATEDIFF(second, prior.AuditDate, a.AuditDate) AS float))
FROM Audit_Opportunity AS a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 a0.*
    FROM Audit_Opportunity a0
    WHERE a0.OpportunityId = a.OpportunityId
    AND a0.Id < a.Id
    AND a0.PreviousStatus = 1
    ORDER BY a0.Id DESC
) prior
WHERE a.Status = 3
AND a.PreviousStatus = 2

If I use a tool (that I shall leave unnamed) to convert the above SQL into equivalent LINQ, I get the following:
var result = _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
    .Where(a => a.Status == OpportunityStatus.Solutioned
                && a.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Qualified)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Duration = _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
            .Where(a0 => a0.OpportunityId == a.OpportunityId
                         && a0.Id < a.Id
                         && a0.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Identified)
            .OrderByDescending(a0 => a0.Id)
            .Select(a0 => EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(a0.AuditDate, a.AuditDate))
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(t => (double?)t.Duration) // Convert duration to double
    .Average(); // Calculate the average

However, I suspect that the above is sufficiently close to your original query, that it might suffer the same translation fate. The "good" SQL query that you included in your post yielded a similar translation.
I found the following "How do I write this cross apply query in LINQ-to-SQL?" question that had a promising answer. Adapting that answer to your case I came up with the following LINQ queries (one using LINQ query syntax, and one using LINQ method syntax).
var result = 
    (from a in _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
     where a.Status == OpportunityStatus.Solutioned
           && a.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Qualified
     from a0 in (
         from a0 in _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
         where a0.OpportunityId == a.OpportunityId
           && a0.Id < a.Id
           && a0.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Identified
         orderby a0.Id descending
         select a0
         )
         .Take(1)
     select (double?)EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(a0.AuditDate, a.AuditDate)
    ).Average();

var result = _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
    .Where(a => a.Status == OpportunityStatus.Solutioned
                && a.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Qualified)
    .SelectMany(a => _context.Set<Audit_Opportunity>()
        .Where(a0 => a0.OpportunityId == a.OpportunityId
                    && a0.Id < a.Id
                    && a0.PreviousStatus == OpportunityStatus.Identified)
        .OrderByDescending(a0 => a0.Id)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(a0 => (double?)EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(a0.AuditDate, a.AuditDate))
    )
    .Average();

These are untested, but hopefully one will translate to a workable SQL form.
Another idea (that I haven't fleshed out) might be to add a second select value (such as a0.Id) to the subquery so that it can no longer be translated as a scalar subquery. To avoid having it optimized out, we would have to reference that value in some harmless way in the outer query, such as where inner.Id > 0.  It isn't pretty, but might force a different translation.
If all else fails, the fallback is to code up and execute a raw SQL query.
(For reference, here is a fiddle containing data, the original posted queries, and the cross apply query from above.)

I never thought to try the query that way, your expression worked perfectly and yielded the exact sql query I was after. Thank you so much for your assistance with this.

@StevenPrice - Out of interest, which LINQ variation worked?

Hi, your last one worked perfectly, the only things I needed to adjust were the enums , the dbcontext, and returning a double instead of a float.
